# Consumable IAP occasionally doesn't give reward & Consumable promo codes don't work at all

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have an app which offers Coins as consumable IAPs. Most of the time this works fine, but occasionally a user will contact me to say although the payment went through and he received an invoice from Apple, he did not receive his Coins.

Also, the app does not handle redeeming consumable Promo codes at all. When redeeming, the App Store shows the message that the IAP has successfully been redeemed, but on opening the App the Coins are never there.

I have followed Apple's recommendation and am adding the transaction observer in the App Delegate file, but still this problem persists. It is driving me nuts, so if anybody familiar with consumable IAPs could take a look at my code and help me I'd be eternally grateful.

Please note: I have tried to adapt this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/1145-in-app-purchases-tutorial-consumables which doesn't add the transaction observer in the App Delegate file, but think I've missed a trick along the way.

**AppDelegate.swift** (only relevant code shown):

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  let iapHelper = IAPHelper()

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(iapHelper) // adds the transaction observer
  }

  func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(iapHelper) // remove the transaction observer
  }
}
```

**IAPHelper.swift:**
Not sure I'm doing things right with the line `static var helper = IAPHelper()`

```
import StoreKit

// Notification that is generated when a product is purchased.
public let IAPHelperPurchaseNotification = "IAPHelperPurchaseNotification"

// Notification that is generated when a transaction fails.
public let IAPHelperTransactionFailedNotification = "IAPHelperTransactionFailedNotification"

// Notification that is generated when cannot retrieve IAPs from iTunes.
public let IAPHelperConnectionErrorNotification = "IAPHelperConnectionErrorNotification"

// Notification that is generated when we need to stop the spinner.
public let IAPHelperStopSpinnerNotification = "IAPHelperStopSpinnerNotification"

// Product identifiers are unique strings registered on the app store.
public typealias ProductIdentifier = String

// Completion handler called when products are fetched.
public typealias ProductsRequestCompletionHandler = (_ success: Bool, _ products: [SKProduct]?) -> ()


open class IAPHelper : NSObject  {

    /// MARK: - User facing API

    fileprivate let productIdentifiers: Set<ProductIdentifier>
    fileprivate var purchasedProductIdentifiers = Set<ProductIdentifier>()

    fileprivate var productsRequest: SKProductsRequest?
    fileprivate var productsRequestCompletionHandler: ProductsRequestCompletionHandler?

    static var helper = IAPHelper()  // is this right??

    /// Init method
    override init() {
        // Set up the list of productIdentifiers
        let PackOf4000Coins =  "com.xxx.xxx.4000Coins"   // This is the ProductID in iTunes Connect
        let PackOf10000Coins =  "com.xxx.xxx.10000Coins"
        let PackOf30000Coins =  "com.xxx.xxx.30000Coins"
        let PackOf75000Coins =  "com.xxx.xxx.75000Coins"
        let PackOf175000Coins = "com.xxx.xxx.175000Coins"
        let PackOf500000Coins = "com.xxx.xxx.500000Coins"
        let RemoveAds =  "com.xxx.xxx.RemoveAds" 
        let PlayerEditor =  "com.xxx.xxx.PlayerEditor" 

        self.productIdentifiers = [PackOf4000Coins, PackOf10000Coins, PackOf30000Coins, PackOf75000Coins, PackOf175000Coins, PackOf500000Coins, RemoveAds, PlayerEditor]

        for productIdentifier in self.productIdentifiers {
            let purchased = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: productIdentifier)
            if purchased {
                purchasedProductIdentifiers.insert(productIdentifier)
                print("Previously purchased: \(productIdentifier)")
            } else {
                print("Not purchased: \(productIdentifier)")
            }
        }

        super.init()

    }

}

// MARK: - StoreKit API

extension IAPHelper {

    public func requestProducts(_ completionHandler: @escaping ProductsRequestCompletionHandler) {
        productsRequest?.cancel()
        productsRequestCompletionHandler = completionHandler

        productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers)
        productsRequest!.delegate = self
        productsRequest!.start()
    }

    public func buyProduct(_ product: SKProduct) {
        print("Buying \(product.productIdentifier)...")
        let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
    }

    public func isProductPurchased(_ productIdentifier: ProductIdentifier) -> Bool {
        return purchasedProductIdentifiers.contains(productIdentifier)
    }

    public class func canMakePayments() -> Bool {
        return SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()
    }

    public func restorePurchases() {
        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }

    public func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        print("Restore queue finished.")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: IAPHelperStopSpinnerNotification), object: nil)
    }

    public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError error: Error) {
        print("Restore queue failed.")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: IAPHelperConnectionErrorNotification), object: nil)
    }

}

// MARK: - SKProductsRequestDelegate

extension IAPHelper: SKProductsRequestDelegate {
    public func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        print("Loaded list of products...")
        let products = response.products
        productsRequestCompletionHandler?(true, products)
        clearRequestAndHandler()
    }

    public func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Failed to load list of products.")
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        productsRequestCompletionHandler?(false, nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: IAPHelperConnectionErrorNotification), object: nil)
        clearRequestAndHandler()
    }

    fileprivate func clearRequestAndHandler() {
        productsRequest = nil
        productsRequestCompletionHandler = nil
    }
}

// MARK: - SKPaymentTransactionObserver

extension IAPHelper: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

    public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case .purchased:
                completeTransaction(transaction)
                break
            case .failed:
                failedTransaction(transaction)
                break
            case .restored:
                restoreTransaction(transaction)
                break
            case .deferred:
                break
            case .purchasing:
                break
            }
        }
    }

    fileprivate func completeTransaction(_ transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
        print("completeTransaction...")
        deliverPurchaseNotificationForIdentifier(transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
    }

    fileprivate func restoreTransaction(_ transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
        guard let productIdentifier = transaction.original?.payment.productIdentifier else { return }

        print("restoreTransaction... \(productIdentifier)")
        deliverPurchaseNotificationForIdentifier(productIdentifier)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
    }

    fileprivate func failedTransaction(_ transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
        print("failedTransaction...")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: IAPHelperStopSpinnerNotification), object: nil)
        if transaction.error!._code != SKError.paymentCancelled.rawValue {
            print("Transaction Error: \(String(describing: transaction.error?.localizedDescription))")
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: IAPHelperTransactionFailedNotification), object: nil)
        } else {
            print("Transaction Error else statement")
        }

        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: IAPHelperTransactionFailedNotification), object: nil)

    }

    fileprivate func deliverPurchaseNotificationForIdentifier(_ identifier: String?) {
        guard let identifier = identifier else { return }

        purchasedProductIdentifiers.insert(identifier)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: identifier)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: IAPHelperPurchaseNotification), object: identifier)
    }
}
```

**GameStoreViewController.swift**:
(I'm concerned I'm not accessing IAPHelper correctly from this VC, it seems wrong)

```
import UIKit    
import StoreKit    

class GameStoreViewController: UIViewController, GetMoneyViewControllerDelegate {    

// A list of available IAPs    
var products = [SKProduct]()  // non-consumables    
var _coinProducts = [SKProduct]() // consumables   

override func viewDidLoad() {    
    super.viewDidLoad()    

    retrieveIAPs()  // Fetch the products from iTunes connect    

    // ** NSNotifications - this is how IAPHelper sends messages for me to handle here ** //    

    // Subscribe to a notification that fires when a product is purchased.    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(GameStoreViewController.productPurchased(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: IAPHelperPurchaseNotification), object: nil)    

    // Subscribe to a notification that fires when a transaction fails.    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(GameStoreViewController.transactionFailed(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: IAPHelperTransactionFailedNotification), object: nil)    

    // Subscribe to a notification that fires when there's a connection error.    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(GameStoreViewController.cannotConnect(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: IAPHelperConnectionErrorNotification), object: nil)    

    // Subscribe to a notification that fires when the activity spinner needs to stop.    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(GameStoreViewController.stopSpinner(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: IAPHelperStopSpinnerNotification), object: nil)    

}    

// Fetch the products from iTunes connect, put into the products array    
func retrieveIAPs() {    
    products = []    
    IAPHelper.helper.requestProducts { success, products in    
        if success {    
            self.products = products!    
            print("Success. Products are: \(self.products)")    
            self._IAPsHaveBeenRetrieved = true    
            self.activitySpinnerStop()    

            // * Set up _coinProducts * //    

            // Filter out 'Other' IAPs    
            self._coinProducts = self.products.filter { $0.productIdentifier != "com.xxx.xxx.PlayerEditor" && $0.productIdentifier != "com.xxx.xxx.RemoveAds" }    

        } else {    
            print("Unable to connect to iTunes Connect. Products are: \(self.products)")    
            self.activitySpinnerStop()    
            self.showAlertWith(Localization("NoConnectionAlertTitle"), message: Localization("NoConnectionAlertMessage"))    
        }    
    }    
}    

// Restore purchases to this device.    
@IBAction func restoreTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {    
    print("Restore button tapped...")    
    activitySpinnerStart()    
    IAPHelper.helper.restorePurchases()    
}    

@IBAction func playerEditorPressed(_ sender: Any) {    
    // First, make sure the user is authorised to make payments on his/her device    
    if IAPHelper.canMakePayments() {    
        // Then, make sure the product has been retrieved from ITC and placed in the products array. If not, show alert    
        if products.count > 0 {    
            activitySpinnerStart()    

            if let theProduct = self.products.first(where: {$0.productIdentifier == "com.xxx.xxx.PlayerEditor"}) {    
                IAPHelper.helper.buyProduct(theProduct)  // Purchasing the product. Fires productPurchased(notification:)    
            } else {    
                print("Could not find com.xxx.xxx.PlayerEditor in playerEditorPressed()")    
            }    

        } else {    
            showAlertWith(Localization("NoConnectionAlertTitle"), message: Localization("NoConnectionAlertMessage"))    
        }    

    } else {    
        showAlertWith(Localization("NoConnectionAlertTitle"), message: Localization("NoIAPAllowedMessage"))    
    }    
}    

@IBAction func removeAdsPressed(_ sender: Any) {    
    // First, make sure the user is authorised to make payments on his/her device    
    if IAPHelper.canMakePayments() {    
        // Then, make sure the product has been retrieved from ITC and placed in the products array. If not, show alert    
        if products.count > 0 {    
            activitySpinnerStart()    

            if let theProduct = self.products.first(where: {$0.productIdentifier == "com.xxx.xxx.RemoveAds"}) {    
                IAPHelper.helper.buyProduct(theProduct)  // Purchasing the product. Fires productPurchased(notification:)    
            } else {    
                print("Uh-oh, could not find com.xxx.xxx.RemoveAds in removeAdsPressed()")    
            }    

        } else {    
            showAlertWith(Localization("NoConnectionAlertTitle"), message: Localization("NoConnectionAlertMessage"))    
        }    

    } else {    
        showAlertWith(Localization("NoConnectionAlertTitle"), message: Localization("NoIAPAllowedMessage"))    
    }    
}    

// MARK: - App Store NSNotification methods    

// When a product is purchased, this notification fires    
@objc func productPurchased(_ notification: Notification) {    
    print("productPurchased(), message received in GameStoreVC")    
    let productIdentifier = notification.object as! String    
    for (index, product) in products.enumerated() {    
        if product.productIdentifier == productIdentifier {    
            activitySpinnerStop()    
            print("Successful purchase! index = \(index), product = \(product.localizedTitle)")    

            // Apply purchase to game    
            switch product.productIdentifier {    
            case "com.xxx.xxx.4000Coins":    
                var coinsTotal = retrieveNumberOfCoins()    
                coinsTotal += 4_000    
                UserDefaults.standard.set(coinsTotal, forKey: "Coins")    

            case "com.xxx.xxx.10000Coins":    
                var coinsTotal = retrieveNumberOfCoins()    
                coinsTotal += 10_000    
                UserDefaults.standard.set(coinsTotal, forKey: "Coins")    

            case "com.xxx.xxx.30000Coins":    
                var coinsTotal = retrieveNumberOfCoins()    
                coinsTotal += 30_000    
                UserDefaults.standard.set(coinsTotal, forKey: "Coins")    

            case "com.xxx.xxx.75000Coins":    
                var coinsTotal = retrieveNumberOfCoins()    
                coinsTotal += 75_000    
                UserDefaults.standard.set(coinsTotal, forKey: "Coins")    

            case "com.xxx.xxx.175000Coins":    
                var coinsTotal = retrieveNumberOfCoins()    
                coinsTotal += 175_000    
                UserDefaults.standard.set(coinsTotal, forKey: "Coins")    

            case "com.xxx.xxx.500000Coins":    
                var coinsTotal = retrieveNumberOfCoins()    
                coinsTotal += 500_000    
                UserDefaults.standard.set(coinsTotal, forKey: "Coins")    

            case "com.xxx.xxx.PlayerEditor":    
                print("Player Editor successfully bought!")    
                // 'Unlock' Player Editor by setting it to 1    
                UserDefaults.standard.set(1, forKey: "PlayerEditor")    

            case "com.xxx.xxx.RemoveAds":    
                print("Remove Ads successfully bought!")    
                // 'Unlock' Remove Ads by setting it to 1    
                UserDefaults.standard.set(1, forKey: "RemoveAds")    

            default:    
                print("No such productIdentifier found")    
            }    

        }    
    }    
}    

// When a transaction fails, this notification fires    
@objc func transactionFailed(_ notification: Notification) {    
    print("transactionFailed(), message received in GameStoreVC")    
    showAlertWith(Localization("TransactionFailedAlertTitle"), message: Localization("TransactionFailedAlertMessage"))    
}    

// When we cannot connect to iTunes to retrieve the IAPs, this notification fires    
@objc func cannotConnect(_ notification: Notification) {    
    print("cannotConnect(), message received in GameStoreVC")    
    showAlertWith(Localization("NoConnectionAlertTitle"), message: Localization("NoConnectionAlertMessage"))    
}    

}    

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource    
extension GameStoreViewController: UITableViewDataSource {    

@objc func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath!) {    
    // * COIN IAPs * //    
    if _selectionIndex == 1 {    
        // First, make sure the user is authorised to make payments on his/her device    
        if IAPHelper.canMakePayments() {    
            // Then, make sure the product has been retrieved and placed in the _coinProducts array. If not, show alert    
            if _coinProducts.count > 0 {    
                let product = _coinProducts[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]    
                IAPHelper.helper.buyProduct(product)  // Purchasing the product. Fires productPurchased(notification:)    

            } else {    
                showAlertWith(Localization("NoConnectionAlertTitle"), message: Localization("NoConnectionAlertMessage"))    
            }    

        } else {    
            showAlertWith(Localization("NoConnectionAlertTitle"), message: Localization("NoIAPAllowedMessage"))    
        }    

        _selectedCoinIndex = indexPath.row  // keep track of the selected coin index    
        iapTableView.reloadData()  // to change colour of selected cell and unselected cells    

    }    
}    

}
```

Further info: the non-consumables ('Player Editor' and 'Remove Ads') work fine, although their Promo Codes only work by opening the Game Store and tapping 'Restore' - they do not work straight after being redeemed.

Can anybody please help?!